# Saving user's changes in an R Shiny application

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I have an application that has two panels: Parameters w/Sub-Script and Parameters, and a radiobutton on the left of the screen. The first panel has a dropdown which the user can go through to change the nodes for each of the options in the dropdown menu.

If you look at the [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gnGH.png), the default dropdown menu option is **reftemp** which has 11 nodes. Some of the nodes across the dropdown menu options have the same variable name. For example, [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yLii.png) shows the nodes for **deltaS**. As you can see, some of the variable names in **reftemp** are the same as some of the variable names in **deltaS.**

I'd like to do two things:

1. Save user's input as they modify the nodes
2. When a change happens to the nodes for **reftemp**, it shouldn't also happen for **deltaS.** Each nodes is associated with it's parent option from the dropdown menu

```
xml_file <- "/Users/fs8/Desktop/Project/MAAT/src/system_models/leaf/leaf_default.xml"
xml_data <- read_xml(xml_file)

leaf_options <- "/Users/fs8/Desktop/Project/MAAT/src/system_models/leaf/leaf_options.xml"
leaf_xml_options <- read_xml(leaf_options)

top_parent <- xml_data %>% xml_find_first(".")
parent_nodes <- xml_data %>% xml_children() %>% xml_name() 

fnames_leaf_node <- xml_data %>% xml_find_first(".//fnames/leaf")
fnames_grandchild_node_names <- xml_children(fnames_leaf_node) %>% xml_name()
fnames_grandchild_node_values <- xml_children(fnames_leaf_node)  %>% xml_text()

pars_leaf_node <- xml_data %>% xml_find_first(".//pars/leaf")
pars_grandchild_node_names <- xml_children(pars_leaf_node) %>% xml_name()
pars_grandchild_node_values <- xml_children(pars_leaf_node) %>% xml_text()

pars_ggc_names <- xml_find_all(pars_leaf_node, ".//*[count(*) > 1]") %>% xml_name()

env_leaf_node <- xml_data %>% xml_find_first(".//env/leaf")
env_grandchild_node_names <- xml_children(env_leaf_node) %>% xml_name()
env_grandchild_node_values <- xml_children(env_leaf_node) %>% xml_text()


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(""),
  fluidRow(
    column(2, 
           wellPanel(
             prettyRadioButtons(
               "parts",
               "Please Select",
               choices = "pars",
               status = "danger",
               fill = TRUE
             )
           )
    ), 
    column(10, 
           bsCollapse(id = "collapse_ex", open = "Parameters", multiple = TRUE,
                      bsCollapsePanel("Parameters w/Sub-Script", 
                                      selectInput("grandchild_params", "Select Parameter", choices = pars_ggc_names),
                                      uiOutput("grandchild_textboxes"),
                                      style = "success"),
                      bsCollapsePanel("Parameters", uiOutput("ui"), style = "info")
           )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$parts, {
    pars_leaf_node <- pars_grandchild_node_names
    
    output$ui <- renderUI({
      fluidRow(
        lapply(pars_leaf_node, function(node_name) {
          if (node_name %in% pars_ggc_names) {
            return(NULL)
          }
          if (node_name %in% pars_grandchild_node_names) {
            node_index <- match(node_name, pars_grandchild_node_names)
            default_value <- pars_grandchild_node_values[node_index]
            
            column(6, textInput(node_name, label = node_name, value = default_value))
          } 
        }) 
      )
    })
    
    output$grandchild_textboxes <- renderUI({
      grandchild_param <- input$grandchild_params # grandchild_param gets the selected parameter from the dropdown menu
      
      reftemp <- xml_data %>% xml_find_first(paste0(".//pars/leaf/", grandchild_param))
      reftemp_names <- xml_children(reftemp) %>% xml_name()
      reftemp_values <- xml_children(reftemp) %>% xml_text()
      
      pars_ggc <- reftemp_names
      
      lapply(pars_ggc, function(pars_node_name) {
        if (pars_node_name %in% reftemp_names) {
          pars_node_index <- match(pars_node_name, reftemp_names)
          pars_def_value <- reftemp_values[pars_node_index]
          
          column(6, textInput(pars_node_name, label = pars_node_name, value = pars_def_value))
        }
      })
    })
  })

}
```

Here's my xml file:

```
<default>
  <fnames>
    <leaf>
      <sys>'f_sys_enzymek'</sys>
      <rh_or_vpd>'f_vpd_from_rh'</rh_or_vpd>
      <sat_vp>'f_sat_vp_allen1998'</sat_vp>
      <solver>'f_solver_brent'</solver>
      <residual_func>'f_residual_func_leaf_Ar'</residual_func>
      <assimilation>'f_assimilation_c3'</assimilation>
      <photorespiration>'f_photorespiration_f1980'</photorespiration>
      <semiana>'f_semiana_quad'</semiana>
      <Acg>'f_Acg_farquhar1980'</Acg>
      <Ajg>'f_Ajg_generic'</Ajg>
      <Apg>'f_Apg_vonc2000'</Apg>
      <etrans>'f_etrans_harley1992'</etrans>
      <gas_diff>'f_gas_diff_ficks_ci'</gas_diff>
      <Alim>'f_Alim_farquhar1980'</Alim>
      <vcmax>'f_vcmax_lin'</vcmax>
      <jmax>'f_jmax_power'</jmax>
      <tcor_jmax>'f_scalar_none'</tcor_jmax>
      <tpu>'f_tpu_lin'</tpu>
      <k_pepc>'f_k_pepc_constant'</k_pepc>
      <rd>'f_rd_lin_vcmax'</rd>
      <rl_rd>'f_scalar_none'</rl_rd>
      <gstar>'f_gstar_f1980'</gstar>
      <ri>'f_r_zero'</ri>
      <rs>'f_rs_medlyn2011'</rs>
      <rb>'f_rb_leafdim'</rb>
      <cica_ratio>'f_cica_ratio_constant'</cica_ratio>
      <d13c>'f_d13c_classical'</d13c>
      <tcor_asc>
        <vcmax>'f_tcor_asc_Arrhenius'</vcmax>
        <jmax>'f_tcor_asc_Arrhenius'</jmax>
        <tpu>'f_tcor_asc_Arrhenius'</tpu>
        <k_pepc>'f_tcor_asc_Arrhenius'</k_pepc>
        <rd>'f_tcor_asc_Arrhenius'</rd>
        <gstar>'f_tcor_asc_quadratic_bf1985'</gstar>
        <tau>'f_tcor_asc_Q10'</tau>
        <Kc>'f_tcor_asc_Arrhenius'</Kc>
        <Ko>'f_tcor_asc_Arrhenius'</Ko>
      </tcor_asc>
      <tcor_des>
        <vcmax>'f_tcor_des_modArrhenius'</vcmax>
        <jmax>'f_tcor_des_modArrhenius'</jmax>
        <tpu>'f_tcor_des_modArrhenius'</tpu>
        <k_pepc>'f_tcor_des_modArrhenius'</k_pepc>
        <rd>'f_scalar_none'</rd>
      </tcor_des>
      <tcor_dep>
        <tpu>'f_tcor_dep_independent'</tpu>
        <rd>'f_tcor_dep_independent'</rd>
        <tau>'f_tcor_dep_independent'</tau>
      </tcor_dep>
      <deltaS>
        <rd>'f_deltaS'</rd>
        <vcmax>'f_deltaS'</vcmax>
        <jmax>'f_deltaS'</jmax>
        <tpu>'f_deltaS'</tpu>
        <k_pepc>'f_deltaS'</k_pepc>
      </deltaS>
      <q10>
        <rd>'f_q10_constant'</rd>
        <vcmax>'f_q10_constant'</vcmax>
        <jmax>'f_q10_constant'</jmax>
        <k_pepc>'f_q10_constant'</k_pepc>
        <tau>'f_q10_constant'</tau>
        <Kc>'f_q10_constant'</Kc>
        <Ko>'f_q10_constant'</Ko>
      </q10>
    </leaf>
  </fnames>
  <pars>
    <leaf>
      <d13c>FALSE</d13c>
      <deltaA_prop>0.15</deltaA_prop>
      <solver_min>-0.0029834</solver_min>
      <solver_max>51.8364435</solver_max>
      <a>0.8</a>
      <f>0.23</f>
      <quantum_yield_to_eff>4</quantum_yield_to_eff>
      <ko_kc_ratio>0.21</ko_kc_ratio>
      <theta_j>0.9</theta_j>
      <theta_col_cj>0.95</theta_col_cj>
      <theta_col_cjp>0.98</theta_col_cjp>
      <avn_25>10</avn_25>
      <bvn_25>30</bvn_25>
      <ajv_25>29</ajv_25>
      <bjv_25>1.63</bjv_25>
      <a_jvt_25>2.59</a_jvt_25>
      <b_jvt_25>-0.035</b_jvt_25>
      <c_jvt_25>-0.0202</c_jvt_25>
      <e_ajv_25>1.01</e_ajv_25>
      <e_bjv_25>0.89</e_bjv_25>
      <atv_25>0</atv_25>
      <btv_25>0.166666666666667</btv_25>
      <akv_25>0</akv_25>
      <bkv_25>20000</bkv_25>
      <flnr>0.09</flnr>
      <fnr>7.16</fnr>
      <Rsa>60</Rsa>
      <Apg_alpha>0</Apg_alpha>
      <g0>0.01</g0>
      <g1_medlyn>4.16</g1_medlyn>
      <g1_leuning>10</g1_leuning>
      <d0>1</d0>
      <g1_ball>6</g1_ball>
      <g_a1_yin>0.85</g_a1_yin>
      <g_b1_yin>0.14</g_b1_yin>
      <rs>6.66666666666667</rs>
      <cica_chi>0.7</cica_chi>
      <rb>0.1</rb>
      <can_ttc>0.01</can_ttc>
      <leaf_width>0.1</leaf_width>
      <ri>6.66666666666667</ri>
      <co2_diff>1.7e-09</co2_diff>
      <hco_co2_ratio>0</hco_co2_ratio>
      <hco_co2_diff_ratio>0.56</hco_co2_diff_ratio>
      <d13c_a>4.4</d13c_a>
      <d13c_b>27</d13c_b>
      <d13c_b_prime>30</d13c_b_prime>
      <d13c_am>1.8</d13c_am>
      <d13c_f>12</d13c_f>
      <a_rdv_25>0</a_rdv_25>
      <b_rdv_25>0.015</b_rdv_25>
      <a_rdn_25>0.5</a_rdn_25>
      <b_rdn_25>0.15</b_rdn_25>
      <rl_rd_ratio>1</rl_rd_ratio>
      <rl_rd_lloyd_a>0.5</rl_rd_lloyd_a>
      <rl_rd_lloyd_b>0.05</rl_rd_lloyd_b>
      <a_rdv_25_t>0.015</a_rdv_25_t>
      <b_rdv_25_t>-5e-04</b_rdv_25_t>
      <home_temp>25</home_temp>
      <reftemp>
        <rd>25</rd>
        <vcmax>25</vcmax>
        <jmax>25</jmax>
        <tpu>25</tpu>
        <k_pepc>25</k_pepc>
        <Kc>25</Kc>
        <Ko>25</Ko>
        <gstar>25</gstar>
        <tau>25</tau>
      </reftemp>
      <atref>
        <rd>2</rd>
        <vcmax>50</vcmax>
        <jmax>100</jmax>
        <tpu>5</tpu>
        <k_pepc>7e+05</k_pepc>
        <Kc>40.49</Kc>
        <Ko>27.84</Ko>
        <gstar>4.325</gstar>
        <tau>2.6</tau>
        <vomax>0</vomax>
      </atref>
      <Ha>
        <rd>69830</rd>
        <vcmax>69830</vcmax>
        <jmax>100280</jmax>
        <tpu>69830</tpu>
        <k_pepc>69830</k_pepc>
        <Kc>79430</Kc>
        <Ko>36380</Ko>
        <gstar>37830</gstar>
        <tau>-41572</tau>
        <vomax>60110</vomax>
      </Ha>
      <Hd>
        <rd>2e+05</rd>
        <vcmax>2e+05</vcmax>
        <jmax>2e+05</jmax>
        <tpu>2e+05</tpu>
        <k_pepc>2e+05</k_pepc>
      </Hd>
      <Topt>
        <rd>27.56</rd>
        <vcmax>27.56</vcmax>
        <jmax>19.89</jmax>
        <tpu>27.56</tpu>
        <k_pepc>27.56</k_pepc>
      </Topt>
      <deltaS>
        <rd>0</rd>
        <vcmax>0</vcmax>
        <jmax>0</jmax>
        <tpu>0</tpu>
        <k_pepc>0</k_pepc>
      </deltaS>
      <a_deltaS_t>
        <rd>490</rd>
        <vcmax>668</vcmax>
        <jmax>660</jmax>
        <tpu>485</tpu>
      </a_deltaS_t>
      <b_deltaS_t>
        <rd>0</rd>
        <vcmax>-1.07</vcmax>
        <jmax>-0.75</jmax>
        <tpu>0</tpu>
      </b_deltaS_t>
      <c_deltaS_t>
        <rd>0</rd>
        <vcmax>0</vcmax>
        <jmax>-0.52</jmax>
        <tpu>0</tpu>
      </c_deltaS_t>
      <q10>
        <rd>2</rd>
        <vcmax>2</vcmax>
        <jmax>2</jmax>
        <tpu>2</tpu>
        <k_pepc>2</k_pepc>
        <Kc>2</Kc>
        <Ko>2</Ko>
        <tau>0.57</tau>
      </q10>
      <a_q10_t>
        <rd>3.22</rd>
      </a_q10_t>
      <b_q10_t>
        <rd>-0.046</rd>
      </b_q10_t>
      <tupp_cox>
        <vcmax>36</vcmax>
        <rd>45</rd>
      </tupp_cox>
      <tlow_cox>
        <vcmax>0</vcmax>
        <rd>5</rd>
      </tlow_cox>
      <exp_cox>
        <vcmax>0.3</vcmax>
        <rd>0.4</rd>
      </exp_cox>
      <gstar_bf_a>0.012</gstar_bf_a>
      <gstar_bf_b>1.68</gstar_bf_b>
      <gstar_bf_c>42.7</gstar_bf_c>
      <R>8.31446</R>
    </leaf>
  </pars>
  <env>
    <leaf>
      <ca_conc>400</ca_conc>
      <o2_conc>0.21</o2_conc>
      <par>1000</par>
      <water_l>0</water_l>
      <sphag_l>0</sphag_l>
      <temp>25</temp>
      <vpd>0</vpd>
      <rh>0.8</rh>
      <atm_press>101325</atm_press>
      <wind>1</wind>
    </leaf>
  </env>
</default>
```